# Asking User to Input First Name & Last Name in 2DArray

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimensionalArray {
    public static void TwoDimensionalArray_M(){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] newString = new String[3][2];
        for (int i = 0; i < newString.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newString[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(i +" "+ j);
                if ( i == j || j>=i) {
                    System.out.println("First Name:");
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Last Name:");
                }

                newString[i][j] = input.nextLine();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("All Value are inputed");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, you want the first dimension of this 2D array to reference a specific person, and the second dimension of this 2D array to reference the particular name (first or last depending on index) of the particular person.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDimensionalArray { 

     public static void TwoDimensionalArray_M(){

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         int numNames=3;

         String[][] newString = new String[numNames][2];

         for (int i=0; i<newString[numLastNames].Length; i++)
         {
              System.out.println("Input first name for index " + i + ":");
              newString[i][0] = input.nextLine();
              System.out.println("Input last name for index " + i + ":");
              newString[i][1] = input.nextLine();
         }

         System.out.println("All values have been inputted.");
     }
}
```